# solve this ordinary differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

i have the differential equation $y'=\frac{y-x}{y-x+1}$, how i solve this?

**try:** i tryed to substitute $u=y-x$, then

$u=y-x\iff y=u+x\Rightarrow y'=u'+1$ then $y'=\frac{y-x}{y-x+1}$ become $u'+1=\frac{u}{u+1}$ and

$u'+1=\frac{u}{u+1}\\
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u}{u+1}-1\\
\frac{du}{dx}=1-\frac{1}{u+1}-1\\
\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{u+1}\\
(u+1)du=-dx\\
\displaystyle\int u+1du=-\int dx\\
\frac{1}{2}u^2+u=-x+C\\
u^2+2u=-2x+\overbrace{2C}^{A}\\
(y-x)^2+2(y-x)=-2x+A\\
y^2-2xy+x^2+2y-2x=-2x+A\\
y^2-2xy+x^2+2y=A\\
y^2-2xy+x^2+2y=A$

exists other way to solve this?

Comment: It's an exact equation. Do you know how to do these?

Comment: @TylerHG i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this ODE is an exact equation. We can write the DE as:

$$(y-x)dx+(x-y-1)dy=0$$

By exact equation, we mean that there is some function $F$ such that $dF=(y-x)dx+(x-y-1)dy$, i.e $dF=F_xdx+F_ydy=0$.  We must also have the condition that the second mixed partial derivatives are equal...this will tell us that such a function $F$ actually exists.  Thus,

$$\partial_y(y-x)=\partial_x(x-y-1)   $$

This is equivalent to saying the the mixed partial derivatives of some well behaved function are equal.  We can proceed by integrating:

$$F(x,y)=\int(y-x)dx=yx-\frac12x^2+\mu(y)    $$

Then,

$$F_y=x+\mu'(y)=x-y-1   $$

$$\mu'(y)=-y-1$$
$$\mu(y)=-\frac12y^2-y+C  $$

This means that

$$F(x,y)=yx-\frac12x^2-\frac12y^2-y+C=0   $$

Which is our desired result.  You can solve for $y$ explicitly I believe.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation